# Modifying a jar: ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag

Tags: java, jar, jvm

I am trying to modify an existing jar to change user credentials because I lost some of the code.

When I run the jar, I get a sql exception because it cannot connect due to bad credentials and in incorrect server url.

I tried extracting the class file responsible for database connections, changing the strings within it(they are hard coded string constants), and dropping the modified class file back in the jar, and executing it.

When I change the password to the correct password which happens to be the same length as the original password, I still get the sql exception. However, when I change the database url, by replacing it with a string of larger length, I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 51 in class file
```

I dont understand what is going on here. From what I can tell, class file size is not stored within the class file. Also, from searching for that particular exception, it appears that other people who get it had corrupted class files, which is a fine answer, but in my case I would expect to get the exception when changing just the password, and it should not depend on string length.

Does anyone understand why this is happening? 
Also, is there a way I can effectively accomplish my goal of changing hard coded strings in a class file and have the jar run normally?

*EDIT*

```
public class TestEdit {
public static final String OUTPUT = "TEST";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(OUTPUT);
}
```

}

So I compiled this class in a jar, and opened the class file, and changed "TEST" to "newTest". I put the class file back in the jar and ran it, and got the exception. Now I edited the class file again, and changed "TEST" to "grow", put it back in and ran it. This time it worked. I would think that if I corrupted the class file by editing it, then the second change would have also thrown the exception, but it doesnt. It seems to have something to do with the string length

Comment: It seems you have damaged one the [constant pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4) entries in the class file, instead of or in addition to changing the password string.

Comment: I dont think thats the case because when I replace the server ip with "localhost", the original value, and put the class file back in the jar, I get sql exception again

Comment: So what does `java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 51 in class file` mean then?

Comment: No idea. If your answer is that this is possible, string replacement in a class file with a string of different length, and I am just doing it wrong, then I will go back and check.

Comment: Modifying a [CONSTANT_Utf8_info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7) is not easy. Make you sure it is stll valid UTF-8.(i.e. take special care for non-ASCII chars)

Comment: I dont think thats it either. I tried a lightweight class to illustrate the example, and edited the original post to explain what I did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant part of the “Java® Virtual Machine Specification” is [§4.4.7, The `CONSTANT_Utf8_info` Structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7)

> The `CONSTANT_Utf8_info` structure is used to represent constant string values:
>
> ```
> CONSTANT_Utf8_info {
>   u1 tag;
>   u2 length;
>   u1 bytes[length];
> }
> ```
>
> The items of the `CONSTANT_Utf8_info` structure are as follows:
>
> tag
>
> The `tag` item of the `CONSTANT_Utf8_info` structure has the value `CONSTANT_Utf8` (1).
>
> length
>
> The value of the `length` item gives the number of bytes in the `bytes` array (not the length of the resulting string).
>
> bytes[]
>
> The `bytes` array contains the bytes of the string.

So if you are looking at it without a dedicated class file parser and recognize the string content, the two bytes right before the first character determine the length of the string (interpreted as big endian unsigned short).

If you overwrite the string contents with a string of the same length (assuming all-ASCII characters), it works, but if you change it to a string of a different length without adapting the `length` information, a class file parser will try to find the next constant pool item at the old position. In your first attempt, where you changed it to a longer string, it found the byte `51`, in other words the character `'3'`, at the place after the original string’s end.

If you adapt the length correctly, there is indeed no other information in the class file depending on the length/positions of these items.